# Thread Blocked Problem when using Reactive RestEasy with GraphQlClient in QUARKUS

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus, reactive, graphql-java

I'm using quarkus version `2.3.0.Final`.

I have a rest endpoint in the `Controller` layer:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Uni<Response> uploadFile(@MultipartForm FormData formData) {

        return documentService.uploadFile(formData).onItem()
                .transform(value -> Response.status(200)
                        .entity(value)
                        .build());
    }
```

and in the `service` layer the code

```
public Uni<?> uploadFile(@NonNull FormData formData) throws Exception {
   // Call to graphQl client using blocking process - the problem occurs here,

   RevisionResponse revisionResponse = entityRepository.createRevision(formData);

   // Do upload to s3 using s3 Async
   return Uni.createFrom()
               .future(
                    storageProviderFactory.getDefaultStorageProvider().upload(formData)))
               .map(storageUploadResponse -> DocumentResponse.builder()
                        .id(revisionResponse.getId())
                        .entityMasterId(revisionResponse.getEntityMasterId())
                        .type(revisionResponse.getType())
                        .path(formData.getFilePath())
                        .description(formData.getDescription())
                        .build());

}
```

and here are the dependencies that I used:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-graphql-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When I run this function, it's being blocked in `entityRepository.createRevision(formData)` (The console show the graphql request log but actually, the request even does not hit the target graphql endpoint)

However, if I add the annotation `@Blocking` in the `controller` layer, everything works as expected.

I also tried with `Uni` response for `Uni<RevisionResponse> revisionResponse = entityRepository.createRevision(formData);` but the same error happens.

Does anyone face these issues, did I config something wrong for the non-blocking processed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who face with the same issue to me, I fix it by wrapping the blocking code with Uni:

`Uni<RevisionResponse> revisionResponse = Uni.createForm().item(entityRepository.createRevision(formData));`

Ref link: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/imperative-to-reactive#running-blocking-code-on-subscription

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning `Uni` from your method, RESTEasy Reactive is running the method on the event loop (see [this](https://quarkus.io/blog/resteasy-reactive-smart-dispatch/) for details).
However, it looks like the call to `entityRepository.createRevision` is blocking IO, which means that the event loop thread is being blocked - something which is not allowed to happen.

Using the `@Blocking` annotation means that the request is being serviced on a worker pool thread, on which you are allowed to block.

Comment: Hi @geoand, thank you for your response.  I also think about that , do we have any solution to fix this ? I want my flow is non-blocking . I also tried with non-blocking graphql client ( return Uni response instead)  , but the error still happens.

Comment: Uni<String> uni = Uni.createFrom()
        .item(this::invokeRemoteServiceUsingBlockingIO)
        .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool()); it seems this code can help. More info: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/imperative-to-reactive#running-blocking-code-on-subscription

Comment: You will need to use a non blocking IO version of the repository.